# Given a list of strings, I want to add the values of a dictionary to a new dictionary if any of the values are equal to the values in the list

Tags: python, dictionary

For example:

```
my_dict = {1: "apple", 2: "pear", 3: "orange", 4: "apple", 5: "grape", 6: "mango", 7: "mango", 8: "pear", 9: "lemon"}
fruit_list = ["apple", "mango", "lemon"]
```

I want to parse through my_dict and if a value in my_dict is equal to either of the values in fruit_list, add that key and value to a new dictionary, so the output dictionary is:

```
{1: "apple", 4:"apple", 6:"mango", 7:"mango", 9:"lemon"}
```

i have already tired using the enumerate function but dont seem to be getting an output.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v in fruit_list}
```